# Errors after upgrading Reactjs from 17.0.2 to 18.2.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I upgraded my front-end reacts from 17.0.2 to 18.2.0 on nodejs 18.11.0 platform (MacOS). However after `yarn start` there throws many errors. The error seems all about nodejs and here is some of them:

```
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:buffer" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
WARNING in ../node_modules/node-domexception/index.js 7:10-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/node-domexception'

ERROR in node:buffer
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:buffer" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:834:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Object.processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:831:8)
    at processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:821:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:965:15)
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1371:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1256:26)

ERROR in node:fs
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:834:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Object.processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:831:8)
    at processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:821:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:965:15)
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1371:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1256:26)

ERROR in node:https
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:https" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:834:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Object.processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:831:8)
    at processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:821:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:965:15)
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1371:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1256:26)

ERROR in node:http
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:http" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:834:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Object.processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:831:8)
    at processResource (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:821:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:965:15)
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1371:12
```

Here is the dependencies in `package.json` (after upgrading of reactjs):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "ethers": "5.7.2",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

What is missing here?

Comment: After removing `import fetch from 'node-fetch'` from the reactjs frontend, the error disappeared.